# Prove that a semigroup which satisfies a certain conditions is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

This is an exercise from "Abstract Algebra" by P.A.Grillet (p.12, ex.2).

> Let $S$ be a semigroup (that is, a set with an associative binary operation) in which there is a left identity element ($\exists e \in S: \forall x \in S \ \ ex = x$) relative to each every element of $S$ has a left inverse ($\forall x \in S \ \ \exists y \in S$ such that $yx = e$). Prove that $S$ is group.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you just post an exercise here?

Comment: Not only is it considered inappropriate to post questions without effort, but it is also bad to post questions whose answers are already easily found here and elsewhere in the Internet. *Try the search features first.* If nobody uses the search feature, then why would we store all of this stuff in the first place?

Comment: @pjs36 I don't know how to solve this, that's why. I think it's an important exercise for my understanding of algebra.

Comment: @rschweib I tried to prove it, but my attempts were't helpful. I didn't know where to start at all, so I showed nothing but excercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following proof, interestingly enough, essentially comes from Section 1.1 of EBBINGHAUS-FLUM-THOMAS *Mathematical Logic*:

First, fix a left identity $e$ (which is not unique, in principle). Let's show that for each $x\in S$ there exists $y\in S$ with $xy=e$. More precisely, any left inverse of $x$ is a right inverse of $x$.

Given $x$, choose $y$ for which $yx=e$, and then choose $z$ for which $zy=e$. Then
\begin{align*}
xy=e(xy)=(zy)(xy)=z((yx)y)=z(ey)=zy=e
\end{align*}

Now let's show that the left unit $e$ is also a right unit, and we are done (this is not in the book cited above): Given $x\in S$, choose $y$ for which $yx=xy=e$, so
$$xe=x(yx)=(xy)x=ex=x$$

So $S$ has a bilateral unit, and each element of $S$ has a bilateral inverse (with respect to this unit, which is unique, etc...), so $S$ is a group.